# Update location when user allows location tracking

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocation

I'm trying to animate where the user is when they accepts location tracking. The Code works when they already have accepted location tracking and then loads the view but I would like to have the view reload when they press accept on location tracking.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //Prepare to get User
     if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedAlways {
         // May need to change to support location based notifications
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        print("hello")

        mapView.setVisibleMapRect(mapView.visibleMapRect, animated: true)
     }else {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
     }
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    mapView.delegate = self

}
```

**Animated to user location Code**

```
//Get user location
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //Show the map at the users current location
    let location = locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02,0.02 )
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        break
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    case .authorizedAlways:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I added the code but the function seems to not be called.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I edited the post. This is for old swift. It should be func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) { }

Comment: Thanks! It works now, but can I make it animate to the current location?

Comment: Yes, this will start updating location and when there is a result your code for "Animated to user location Code" would be called

Answer (score 0):

All methods used to update locations in `CLLocationManager` are asynchronous, so there might be a delay from the user allowing location access to the location update actually happening regardless of the implementation of your code.

However, by calling `CLLocationManager().requestLocation()` inside `locationManager(didChangeAuthorizationStatus)` you can ensure that you receive a location update as close as possible to the acceptance of location usage.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    case .authorizedAlways:
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

This will automatically call your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method as soon as the asynchronous `requestLocation` function finishes execution.